# Prolog successively binding within interval

Tags: random, prolog

I'm designing an AI for a simple game and I wish to implement a random movement. But this movement must satisfy the game rules.

Choosing random integers can be done with `random_between/3`, but the variable binding occurs only once. So if I check the rules after the binding, in case of failure the function will return `false`.

I want to bind a variable with a random integer like `between/3` does: try some value and in case of failure, come back and try another binding. But `between/3` is not random.

Is there a simple way to achieve this or similar results? (on SWI-Prolog)

Comment: @lurker `random_between/3` from SWI succeeds only once. Something like Paulo's suggestion is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can write something like:

```
?- repeat, random_between(1, 10, X).
X = 6 ;
X = 2 ;
X = 9 ;
X = 5 ;
...
```

Just make sure that you cut the choice-point after you find a satisfactory answer.